# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b

Tags: python, unicode, codec

I'm using the following code from [here](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) (with minor edits):

```
import _pickle as cPickle 

def unpickle(file):
    fo = open(file, 'rb')
    dict = cPickle.load(fo)
    fo.close()
    return dict

unpickle('data_batch_1')
```

When I run the code, I get the following, provided that I'm using `Python 3.5.2`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "open_batch.py", line 10, in <module>
    unpickle('data_batch_1')
  File "open_batch.py", line 5, in unpickle
    dict = cPickle.load(fo)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since it fails on the encoding of the characters

Try using latin

```
cPickle.load(file, encoding='latin1')
```

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
dict = cPickle.load(fo)
```

in *unpickle* function with:

```
dict = cPickle.load(fo, encoding='latin1')
```